# {'code': 'NoMatch'} OSRM API: What does it mean? And how can I avoid it?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I have RAW GPS trackers data, when I match those GPS coordinates to nearest NodeID, it gives me the No Match Error. I am using the following code snippet:

```
import requests

url =  'http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/73.8984366,33.63299;73.132215,33.5563133'


payload = {"steps":"true","geometries":"geojson", "annotations" :"true", "radiuses": "0.5;40.5"}

response = requests.get(url,params=payload)

data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Can anybody tell me which thing I am doing wrong and how can I overcome this?

Comment: There aren't any roads on OpenStreetMap in your area: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/33.6372/73.8703 - you need to add those roads first before they show up in OSRM.

Comment: @mmd thanks for your response. There are roads in my area and have very rich infrastructure and network of roads., I have plotted these GPS points data on UBER'S  kepler.gl , these points are showing near the roads. But in my case when i want to get the node ID using OSRM API, it showing me no match.

Comment: DId you check the link I posted? Does it match the area you're looking at?

Comment: Also your first `radius` of `0.5` meters is pretty small. Try to increase it to match the accuracy of your coordinates.